# Running multiple instances of docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, shell

I have a pretty regular docker-compose file shown below.
Is there an easy way to run multiple instances of this?

I have considered using a shell script that will check for running instances, generate a temp docker-compose file with modified params like port, container name etc, and then run compose up on that file.

I'm hoping there're cleaner options?

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    image: image:13.0
    container_name: main

    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - database
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
    volumes:
      - ./pip.conf:/etc/pip.conf
      - utilities:/mnt/utilities
      - extra-addons:/mnt/extra-addons
      - enterprise-addons:/mnt/enterprise-addons

    environment:
      - HOST=db
      - USER=kaniel
      - PASSWORD=outis

  
  database:
    image: postgres:13
    container_name: db

    restart: always
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data

    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=kaniel
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=outis
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres


volumes:
  pgdata:

  utils:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: 'none'
      o: 'bind'
      device: '${PWD}/utils'

  custom:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: 'none'
      o: 'bind'
      device: '${PWD}/custom'

  enterprise:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: 'none'
      o: 'bind'
      device: '${PWD}/enterprise'
```

Comment: your option is to use `docker swarm` :)

Comment: Or kubernetes (minikube or something like that).

Comment: Can you use these in a local dev env as well?